# RxJS: Check token validity before calling S3 List, and wait for the token in case it is invalid

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-s3, rxjs

Please bear with me, as the question is long and detailed, and I am fairly new to RxJS.

**I am attempting to create Amazon S3 browser in Angular which looks like Windows Explorer.**

[Something like this...](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/00a_file_explorer_windows_10_style.png)

The left list will contain all the root folders (and it will not be a tree view), and when clicked on any root folder, the subfolders and files inside it will be shown in the right-side details view.

I need a new S3 Access token for each of the root folders in the left-list. I have a backend service which does so. This token is valid for certain time duration. So the cases in which the current token is invalid are:-

1. If the user clicks on some other root folder in left list.
2. If the token expiry is reached.

This is what I have written to manage this token expiry condition :-

```
private accessTokenSource: BehaviorSubject<AccessToken | null> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
accessToken$ = this.accessTokenSource.asObservable();

getAccessToken() {
    return this.http.get(${this.accessTokenEndpoint}).pipe(
        tap((accessToken) => {
            // set Access token in a subject
            this.accessTokenSource.next(accessToken);
        }),
        switchMapTo(timer(55*60*1000).pipe(
            tap(() => {
                // reset access token in subject since now token is invalid - Expiry case
                this.accessTokenSource.next(null);
            })
        ))
    );
}

// Whoever subscribes to this will fetch the token and start the expiration timer
```

Since not wanting to expose access token fetching logic in view layer, each of my left-list and details component calls a method `getDetails(currentPrefix: string)` in the s3Service. This method first checks validity of the token for being able to call S3 API, and then calls `listObjects` operation and returns the result. Here's what I have so far :-

```
// Checks the validity of token for the current prefix
checkAccessTokenValidity(currentPrefix: string) {
    let isTokenValid: boolean = true;

    // This uses access token set in the subject
    // According to me, it will be reset by the timer's tap operation (when it expires)
    const sub = this.accessToken$.subscribe((token) => {
        // Check token's expiry or usability for current folder and update isTokenValid accordingly
        if(!token || !currentPrefix.includes(token.rootFolder)) {
            isTokenValid = false;
        }
    });
    sub.unsubscribe();

    return isTokenValid;
}


// Public method to call from list and details components
getDetails(currentPrefix: string) {
    const isTokenValid = this.checkAccessTokenValidity(currentPrefix);
    if(!isTokenValid) {
        // This will fetch the token and start the TIMER
        this.getAccessToken().subscribe(() => {});
    }
    // I think that this will not work, since if getAccessToken takes time,
    // then accessToken$ will still be invalid!
    const objectList$ = this.accessToken$.pipe(
        map(token => {
            // S3 List Objects method here, with current token
        })
    )
}
```

How do I solve the problem of checking token validity and then waiting for my service to return new valid token in order to call the S3 API? Any help would be really appreciated. This approach may be dead wrong as well, so please feel free to correct me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that there is no need to create another subscription just to get the current value of a `BehaviorSubject`.

This means that these lines:

```js
const sub = this.accessToken$.subscribe((token) => {
      if(!token || !currentPrefix.includes(token.rootFolder)) {
        isTokenValid = false;
      }
    });
sub.unsubscribe();
```

could be replaced with

```js
const isTokenValid = !!this.accessTokenSource.value;
```

As you already mentioned, `getAccessToken` takes some time, meaning you can't get its result synchronously.

A quick fix would be this:

```js
const tokenValid$ = of(this.accessTokenSource.value); 

const tokenInvalid$ = merge(
  // Not interested in the values emitted as side effects are produced in `tap()`
  // With this, we're just subscribing. This way, an HTTP call will be made
  this.getAccessToken().pipe(ignoreElements()),

  // `accessTokenSource` is a `BehaviorSubject` and we don't want its current value,
  // that's why we're skipping it. Next time it emits, it will have the value returned from `getAccessToken`
  this.accessTokenSource.pipe(skip(1))
);

const objectList$ = iif(() => isTokenValid, tokenValid$, tokenInvalid$);
```

`iff()` is used to decide at **subscription time** to which observable to subscribe.

`if(() => booleanValue, subscribeToThisIfTrue, subscribeToThisIfFalse)`

This way, when you subscribe to `objectList$`, it will pick up the proper observable, depending on whether the token is valid or not.

Comment: Great. This clarified most of the things - just one follow-up question - what is the iif(() => {...}) at the end? Edit:- Read up the documentation - and that makes total sense! Thanks a ton. i will let you know how that goes.

Comment: I will try this out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I've added a few explanations regarding `iif()`. Sure!

Comment: Hi @Andrei, I tried this implementation out, this makes sense. However. I am running into the problem where I get hundreds of getAccessToken() requests (until call stack overflows), ONLY when I refresh the page on the route that needs to call getFolderContents(). If I navigate from somewhere else to this route, just a single request is sent. I suspect merge(...) has something to do with it?

Comment: ‘merge’ makes sure that the request is made, so I don’t think there’s the problem. Do you subscribe to objectList$ in multiple places? If not, could you show the code for  getFolderContents?

Comment: Sorry I meant `getDetails()`, `getFolderContents()` was the old name for that method. I intend to pipe the received token to get details from S3, hence the name `objectList$`, for the time-being I have named it `newToken$` and just subscribing in one place as `newToken$.subscribe(() => { })` to sanity check if it works.

Comment: Hm, then are you calling `getAccessToken()` anywhere else, apart from `merge`?

Comment: Nope, that's what has got me so confused, no apparent reason why this is happening...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213244/discussion-between-saketk21-and-andrei-gtej).